Blazor PWA with shared database between all uses in offline mode
A requirement for our Blazor PWA application is all data persisted on client computer must be shared between all users on that machine.
Is there a way to share data between all uses on client machine using Blazor PWA?
I have looked at indexeddb, SqliteWasmHelper, but it is not possible to share data between different windows users or google account users.
In advance thanks!
